# integration example with matlab

Tags: matlab, calculus, integral

Can someonse show me how to calculate the following in matlab:

[image]

where

```
g = 9.91
As = 1000
z = 10
zv = 30
zD = 10
pz = 999
Az = 500
```

Comment: You are aware that this is trivial to do analytically?

Comment: Please note that assigning a value to `z` is meaningless, since its the variable of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are a couple of ways to go about this:

#### Analytical approach

Like Rudy commented, this is a trivial integral to do analytically because it's the [integral of a power](http://www.ditutor.com/integrals/power_integral.html) (z<sup>1</sup>). Its indefinite integral would be:

> `F(z) = (g/As)(z2/2 - zvz)pzAz`

According to the [Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part), the definite integral is computed by substituting the integral bounds into `F(z)`, that is:

> `ST = F(zd) - F(0) = (g/As)(zD2/2 - zvzD)pzAz`

In MATLAB, that would be:

```
ST = g / As * zD * (zD / 2 - zv) * pz * Az
ST = 
      -1.2375e+06
```

#### Numerical approach

If, for some reason, you want to calculate that numerically by approximating the integral, you can use the [`trapz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) function for this:

```
dz = 0.001; z = 0:dz:zD;
y = g / As * (z - zv) * pz * Az;
ST = trapz(z, y)
ST = 
      -1.2375e+06
```

or make an even cruder approximation with a simple sum:

```
ST = sum(y * dz)
ST =
      -1.2387e+06
```